# Selection based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to select Customers based on the Channel and Organisation i.e., the order of selection of Customers should be based on Channel - 10,40,20,30 and all the organisations for that customer needs to selected as well.

For Eg if a customer has a Channel 10 and 40 - then Channel 10 takes a priority over 40 and so on. Also, For every Customer, if they have 2 Organisations, then they both need to be selected.

[image]

Hope I am clear. Please can somebody help me with this query.

Comment: Also, is this ordering of Channels arbitrary - `10,40,20,30` - or is there a column somewhere which reflects the priority?

Comment: Why doesn't channel 20 have precedence over channel 40 for K3? Is this a typo?

Comment: @APC : Sorry about the image. I did not realise that.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : That is my rule. Order of priority of channel is 10,40,20,30

Comment: Thank you. I misread your request. Sorry. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Oracle's `KEEP FIRST` to apply an order of precedence:

```
select
  min(channel) keep (dense_rank first order by 
    case channel when 10 then 1 when 40 then 2 when 20 then 3 else 4 end),
  customer,
  org
from mytable
group by customer, org
order by customer, org;
```

The same can be achieved with the standard-complient `ROW_NUMBER`:.

```
select channel, customer, org
from
(
  select
    t.*
    row_number() over (partition by customer, org
                       order by case channel when 10 then 1
                                             when 40 then 2
                                             when 20 then 3
                                             else 4 end) as rn,
  from mytable t
)
where rn = 1
order by customer, org;
```

Add a `WHERE` clause, if you want to restrict this to certain customers, channels or organizations.

Comment: Not a typo. I need Channel 40 that should have a higher priority over 20 and 30

Comment: Ah, I see, 10,40,20,30 is the order of precedence. Sorry. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What makes it hard is that the ordering is custom. Otherwise it is a simple job for WINDOW FUNCTIONS.

```
WITH CustomOrder AS (
    SELECT 10 as channel, 1 as ordr UNION ALL
    SELECT 40 as channel, 2 as ordr UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 as channel, 3 as ordr UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 as channel, 4 as ordr)
,TableWithOrder AS (
    SELECT c.Channel
        ,c.Customer
        ,c.Org
        ,co.ordr
    FROM Customers c 
    INNER JOIN CustomOrder co ON co.channel=c.channel
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(Channel) OVER (PARTITION BY customer,org ORDER BY ordr ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDEING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as channel
    ,Customer
    ,Org
FROM TableWithOrder
```

Comment: This works well for me. Thank you very much. Just wondering what would be more efficient as a query though - using Partitions or Dense Rank

Comment: I do not understand your question. Dense_rank is a window function as well, it accepts window partitioning. In order to determine performance I would suggest studying the query plans for both  versions.

Comment: @SDR . . . Your should try both methods on your data and your system and let us know.